# Get .Net Core Api to generate text/html response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an Asp.Net Core 2.0 API for which I need to generate a response of content-type text/html.  Requests are currently generating 406 errors.  How do I get my api to generate a response type of 'text/html'?

```
[HttpGet("api/scoInfo/")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetScoInfo([FromQuery]int activityId, [FromQuery]int studentId, [FromQuery] long timeStamp)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var learningTask = await _context.LearningTasks.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == activityId);

    if (learningTask == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    //Note the following worked in .Net 4.6.1 - it does not work in .Net Core
    //var jsonstring =new StringContent(learningTask.Data, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/html") ;

    var jsonstring = learningTask.Data;  // json string looks something like this...."{Data="{\"status\":\"failed\" etc...}"


    return Ok(jsonstring);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide code example of your API and what exactly are you returning ?

Comment: Note - API is not consumed by view but by JavaScript player - over which I do not have control

Comment: @RoddyBalkan Please add code to the question instead of as comment.

Comment: Which accept-headers do you get with the request?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to give some content that isn't html (your example seems to say it's JSON) an html content-type because that's what the (plainly broken...) client expects?

Answer (score 0):

Invoke an MVC view using `return View();` or `return View(model);` if you have a model. You will need to have defined a view that associates with the controller using [MVC conventions](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/219d4d/conventions-in-mvc/). This is the standard way to serve html in MVC, where MVC controllers and API controllers are now unified.

Comment: Note - API is not consumed by view but by JavaScript player - over which I do not have control –